# Why does my reverse integers function specifically not work with a positive int of 2 digits? C++

Tags: c++

```
    //declare variables
    int size;
    string str = to_string(x);  //stores parameter number
    string str2;     //stores reversed number
    int reverseInt = 0;
    size = str.size();
    
    //if the input integer is positive reverses using the for loop.
    if (x > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            str2[size-1-i] = str[i];
        }
    }
    //exception handling for underflow/overflow
    try 
    {
        reverseInt = stoi(str2);      
    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return reverseInt;
```

Above is my the one part of the function that should affect a positive integer of any kind, I have everything else commented out to make sure that there's no external effect. This is the problem somewhere. What I don't understand is why an input of 19, for example, gets me 916... where does the 6 come from? I cannot comprehend how I got that 6. The worst part of the frustration is that -19 gets converted perfectly, using basically the same method. 10 gives me 16, 15 gives me 516, and 10 gives me 16, it just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I'm a bit curious what is the expected result of assigning a value to `str2[size-1-i]` while `str2` has no size assigned to it yet. I suppose `str2` is an empty string, what happens when you assign a character at some position bigger than `0` or `1` to it, for example when `x` is 1000 or greater ?

Comment: `str2` is empty so there is no storage (or not enough). You are overwriting something you shouldn't. You can reverse the string by `std::string str2(str.rbegin(), str.rend());`. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Comment: You are actually trying to reverse a string, not an integer. The whole reversing routine does not depend at all on the string contents, it could be "19",  but it could also be "19.5e7" or "Hahah" or "Farewell, baby!" as well.

Comment: As for what happens when x > 1000, as stated in the title, it only malfunctions for size 2 or a double-digit number. 100 works. 999999 works. 10-99 does not.

Comment: In response to CiaPan, while I agree that it could work like that if that function was just in main with some random variable x, it's a function with an int parameter, if the input isn't int the problem won't be the function, and that has little to nothing to do with the question. 
In sum: very helpful.

Comment: Skullruss: I'm sorry but I can't see _'it's a function with an int parameter'_ because you did't show the function declaration. Anyway, when I see 'reverse an integer' I imagine a computing routine, which decomposes an input value by arithmetic operations to obtain consecutive digits as arithmetic values 0..9 and then combines those digit values into a result, again by arithmetic operations. What you did is not reversing an integer in the above sense, but rather transforming an int into a string (text) representation, _reversing the string_ and then parsing the string back into an integer.

Comment: What concerns the error itself, KamilCuk pointed out the important omission in your code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68196005/733637) so I didn't have to do that. However, I am interested in good communication here, hence my comment about a vague description in your question – just to suggest a more precise description the next time.

Comment: You're correct, that's my bad for not showing the function declaration, but using reserve to allocate memory did not inherently solve the issue, instead I went about using the modulus operator to get the last digit, and slap it into a new int, which sounds similar to the method you described.

Answer (score 1):

You did not allocate memory for `str2`.

```
string str2;     //stores reversed number
str2.reserve(str.size());
```

Use `.at(...)` instead of `[...]` to catch such mistakes.